# highcharts 'download png/jpeg image' option not working for more than 2000 data points

Tags: highcharts

This issue is appearing only if we have more than 2000 data points. If attempting to download any file type for my plot from the context menu in the upper right, the below error page is appearing and no file is downloaded.

[image]

[image]

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @user3916928, Could you add more information about the problem? I've created a simple live example with exporting 3000 data points: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sy5wm4oa/ and everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: @ppotaczek, thanks for your comment. Although I'm unable to download the chart as png image with your fiddle. It says '0x04 error when performing chart generation: please check your input data'. Could you please check once.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the exact problem. Indeed, 'Download PNG image' doesn't work and it looks like a bug in Highcharts Export Server. Could you report the problem on GitHub? Repository: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues Similar problem: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10556